# How do I let Selenium driver click on link which is dynamically created through JavaScript

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate actions and unable to select an element due to its dynamic nature.
I am running Selenium web driver on ruby and am trying to select value that is not present in page source.

```
<a class="linkOtherBrowser" onclick="addChangeStatusField('InitialSelectionPage');submitFormByAction('ChangeStep');return false;" href="#"><div class="processBarElement noSelected">
<div class="whiteBeforeProcessBarTitles"></div>Initial Selection</div>
<div class="endOfElementOfProcessBar"></div></a>
```

I am trying to select value "Initial Selection" from above.

Could anyone pls help out?

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: #browser.find_element(:partial_link_text, "Initial").click
#browser.find_element(:link_text,"Initial Selection").click
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]/text()").click

I tried above, but none of it works

Answer (score 0):

As the HTML is generated by Javascript, You need to **inspect the DOM** instead of viewsource and write the element locator code accordingly.

Note: In IE, Firefox or Chrome you can press F12 key to see the developer tools and use the inspect element option to check the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever element is generated dynamically is added in your DOM. WebDriver has capability of clicking on elements are the visible on UI and hence if the generated element is visible to regular user's you can click on the element easily.

To do so, you need to identify the best selector for that newly generated click, could be xpath or css. Once you identify the selector you can consider clicking clicking using following code

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='NAME_TITLE']"));
element.click();
```

OR

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.css("a[title='NAME_TITLE']"));
element.click();
```

There are more options within your By.class on picking the element in best way